# sending email in c# using port no

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email

I want to send email from yahoo to yahoo bt failed to send it. I use network received. Please review my code credential. There is no exception or error but when the mail box is opened, there is no email. I used a `label` which show succesfull text, but at that time, it is not showing successfull.

**.aspx code:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    Message from: <asp:TextBox ID="text1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    Message To: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    Message subject: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

   <asp:Button ID="b1" runat="server" OnClick="click" />

   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

**.aspx.cs:**

```
public void click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         //mail message
         MailMessage mM = new MailMessage();

         //Mail Address
         mM.From = new MailAddress(text1.Text);

         //emailid to send
         mM.To.Add(TextBox1.Text);

         //your subject line of the message
         mM.Subject = "your subject line will go here.";

         //now attached the file
         //mM.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\\attachedfile.jpg"));

         //add the body of the email
         mM.Body = "Your Body of the email.";
         mM.IsBodyHtml = false;

         //SMTP 
         SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();

         //your credential will go here
         SmtpServer.Credentials = new 

         System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

         //port number to login yahoo server
         SmtpServer.Port = 587;

         //yahoo host name
         SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
         SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

         SmtpServer.Send(mM);
         Label1.Text = "successfull";
         //Send the email

         //end of try block
         //end of catch
     }
     catch(Exception ee){
         Console.Write(ee);
     }
}
```

Comment: Change your password immediately.

Comment: You are catching the Exception and printing it to the console. Can you show us the error that's being printed? Or is there no error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the code itself has something wrong. I almost use the same code as yours and it works well.

I think there is something wrong with your settings, Please check:

1. if the recipient's email address in your TextBox1 has already exist
2. If the username and password for the credentials are all correct

And I don't set the Port property in my code. If all are right.Please show your exception info here.